# Каково происхождение слов «шалаш», «шаль», «шале»?

Tags: этимология

Слова шалаш (легкая постройка), шаль (большой теплый платок), шале (крестьянский дом в швейцарских Альпах) созвучны и обозначают предметы, служащие защитой / укрытием от непогоды.
Могут ли они происходить из одного языка и, тем более, от одного корня?

Comment: В кыргызском языке есть слово ШАЛ иранского происхождения - "грубая шерстяная ткань кустарного производства". Возможно первые ШАЛАШИ накрывали подобной тканью. Отсюда и схожесть названия.

Answer (score 2):

Слово "шаль"(перс. شال‎, санскр. साडी) пришло из санскрита,  древнего литературного языка Индии, и обозначает  большой вязаный или тканый платок. У Фасмера:

> ж., род. п. -и. Через франц. châle — то же или нем. Sсhаl — то же
> (начиная с 1810 г.; см. Клюге-Гётце 505) из англ. shawl от нов.-перс.
> šâl, которое производят из Индии; см. Литтман 113; Локоч 143;
> Гамильшег, ЕW 202. Польск. посредство (Преобр., Труды I, 86) столь же
> маловероятно, сколь и вост. происхождение (см. Мi. ТЕl. 2, 162), о
> котором можно говорить только в отношении диал. шала «шерстяная
> платяная ткань», кавк. (Хожд. Котова 112). Происхождение слова шаль в
> этимологическом онлайн-словаре Фасмера М.

Многие учёные полагают, что слово шаль - из французского, во французском - с 70-х годов XVIII века в общем употреблении как "кашемировая шаль". Во французский и английский языки слово шаль попало из Азии, но разными путями. Некоторые считают слово персидским, указывая при этом, что слово шаль известно многим языкам Востока. Полагают, что само слово происходит от названия старинного города Шалят в Индии. В любом случае шаль покрывает плечи, укрывает от холода.

Шале и шалаш - тоже укрытия, только это не одежда, а жилища.

Шале ( от французского chalet ) - сельский домик, или альпийская хижина.

Первоначально альпийское шале - это надёжно построенное из массивного бруса жилище, которое должно защищать от непогоды в горах. Отличительной особенностью шале является крыша, козырек которой выступает далеко вперед, что позволяет защищать фундамент от намокания. А  зимой такая конструкция крыши удерживает снег, что придаёт необычайную красоту и не дает теплу уходить из дома.

Шала́ш - древнерусское заимствование из тюркских. По Фасмеру, родственно тур. sаlаš, азерб. šаlаš «шалаш, палатка». Сюда же укр. шалаш, польск. sałasz, словацк. sаlаš.

Само слово шалаш перекочевало в русский язык где-то в 10 - 12 веках, а славянские аналоги шалаша - это, наверное, сень (не путать с сенями) - что-то типа временного укрытия, дающего тень и вежа - временная сторожевая будка, временное укрытие, сторожевой пост.
По Далю:

> Шалаш — м. балаган, сень, куща, конура, наскоро сделанный в лесу или в
> поле приют, из подручных припасов. Лубяной, рогожный, берестовый
> шалаш; шалаш на тетеревей из лапнику, соломы.

Но вот какой шалаш снится пушкинской Татьяне:

> Вдруг меж дерев шалаш убогой;
>
> Кругом все глушь; отвсюду он
>
> Пустынным  снегом занесен,
>
> И ярко светится окошко,
>
> И в шалаше и крик и шум;
>
> Медведь промолвил: «Здесь мой кум:
>
> Погрейся у него немножко!» И в сени
>
> прямо он идет И на порог ее кладет.
>
> XVI
>
> Опомнилась, глядит Татьяна:
>
> Медведя нет; она в сенях;
>
> За дверью крик и звон стакана

Получается, по значению шалаш и шале совпадают - изба в лесу, укрытие. И корень похож. Может, просто пока не нашли французского соответствия шалашу, а chalet не взяли во внимание.

А вот шаль - это уже омоним, но в праиндоевропейском, возможно, корень был один - шал со значением "крыть".

Так что все три слова в далёкой истории могут быть однокоренными, но это не доказано (пока). Попробуйте доказать, будет очередное открытие.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила, за приведенную Вами цитату, где «шалаш» выглядит куда более основательно, чем современный (см. Википедию). В не самом далеком прошлом, как оказывается,  шалаш мог иметь (светящееся!) окно и даже сени. 
В нац.корпусе нашлось еще одно упоминание о таком «шалаше»: «Обогнув Васильевский остров … достигли того места на берегу залива, где обыкновенно останавливается Борис Ильич для охоты и где построил он на свой счет шалаш, стоивший ему «около семи рублей». [С. П. Жихарев. Записки современника (1806-1809)]».